# I need current user to see only his todo list and got an error: undefined method `lists' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need the current user to see only his own todo list after login. (Using Devise) And I got error "Undefined method "lists" for nil:NilClass.
I made changes in the User model (has_many :lists), as well in the List model (belongs_to :user).
I got an error undefined method `lists' for nil:NilClass

Lists Controller code is

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController  
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

    def index
        @lists = current_user.lists.order('created_at') <----- error occurs here
    end 

    def new
        @list = current_user.lists.new
    end

    def create
        @list = current_user.lists.new list_params

        @list.save

        redirect_to lists_path
    end

    def edit
        @list = List.find params[:id]
    end

    def update
        @list = List.find params[:id]

        @list.update list_params

        redirect_to lists_path
    end

    def destroy
        @list = List.find params[:id]

        @list.destroy

        redirect_to lists_path
    end

    private

    def list_params
        params.require(:list).permit(:title)
    end

end
```

schema.rb code

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_05_10_131407) do

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.boolean "completed"
    t.integer "list_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["list_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_list_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

And Index.html code if need

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>ToDo List</h1>

    <div class="buffer-top"><%= link_to "New List", new_list_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>

    <div class="buffer-top">
        <% @lists.each do |list| %>
            <%= render partial: 'list', object: list %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not authenticating the User for the index view, the error is because there is no `current_user`, so you are calling the method `lists` on `nil`.

You should check if there is a user first

```
def index
  if user_signed_in?
   @lists = current_user.lists.order('created_at')
  else
    <!-- Do somthing here, what do you want if no user is there? -->
  end
end
```

Not exactly sure what you would want if there is no user so you'll have to fill that part in.  The issue really here is you are basically creating a view where you want a user, but you also do not require a user, the user's `@lists` would likely be better served on a different view if you do not want to require a user here.

You will also have to fix the view to check as well.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="buffer-top">
    <% @lists.each do |list| %>
        <%= render partial: 'list', object: list %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you really want to go with this setup then you could DRY it up by removing the lines inside the `index` method and changing the view.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="buffer-top">
    <% current_user.lists.order('created_at').each do |list| %>
        <%= render partial: 'list', object: list %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```